# C GPIO for loop

Tags: c, loops, gpio, lpc

I have an LPC board and I need to iterate through the pins and check if they are high or low when I connect them with some LEDs/Wire. Problem I find is that the pins are not in a specific order. I have 20 Input GPIOs and 20 Outputs.

I have defined the pins as macro expressions Eg. `#define GPIO1 0,1 #define GPIO2 1,19` and then I stored them in an array Eg. `gpio_outputs[] = {GPIO1, etc};` but if I try to do a for loop of this array it tells me "too few arguments"

```
for (i=0;i<sizeof(gpio_outputs);i++){
//  Chip_GPIO_SetPinDIROutput(LPC_GPIO_PORT, gpio_outputs[i]);
//}
```

The prototype for `Chip_GPIO_SetPinDIROutput` is:

```
Chip_GPIO_SetPinDIROutput(LPC_GPIO_PORT, PIN_INDEX, PIN_NUMBER);
```

Now, from what I've been reading, macro expression don't work with this. So my question is how can I iterate through each GPIO without having to do it manually for all 40?

Comment: Define an array with the right order of the pins, then iterate over it.

Comment: Are all the 20 pins in the same actual port? What are the two numbers in your macro? And no, macros don't work like that, you're going to have to have a table that has the actual data you need. What is the difference between a "pin index" and a "pin number"?

Comment: There's two rows. Each row has an index. Eg. left hand row index 0, right hand row 1. That's not actually how it is but easier to explain. The actual GPIO numbers are all over the place. Eg. I have a 1, 19 after pin 0, 2.
https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/1200x900/1342-00.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
struct GPIO_Attr { uint8_t pinIndex, pinNumber; };
struct GPIO_Attr gpio_outputs[] = { {GPIO1}, {GPIO1} }; // Extra '{}' is necessary to initialize GPIO_Attr fields
for (i=0;i<sizeof(gpio_outputs)/sizeof(gpio_outputs[0]);i++){
    Chip_GPIO_SetPinDIROutput(LPC_GPIO_PORT, gpio_outputs[i].pinIndex, gpio_outputs[i].pinNumber);
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me why are you dividing sizeof(gpio_outputs) by sizeof(gpio_outputs[0]) ?

Comment: It's a common idiom for getting array length at C. 
sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]) => total_array_size / array_element_size => length.